# How to make notes read-only?

Tags: macos, ios, notes.app

Can I set the default notes read-only, so I can't edit them  unintentionally?

Note: I don't want to lock them, cause then I can't read them, unless I can edit them too. I want to be able to read them but not edit them by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no default way to do this in either iOS or macOS.

Recommendations from several similar questions on this site (use the Search function to find them) include using 3rd party applications instead or taking a screenshot of the Note (and locking the original) so it can't be edited.

Comment: but we need to be able to copy and page the text such as command or something

Comment: what does locking do?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo See [this](https://support.apple.com/guide/notes/lock-your-notes-not28c5f5468/mac).